# Using logger in Rails 4

Tags: logging, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a Rails 4 project, and I can't seem to make anything show up in my development log when I call `Rails.logger.debug "test"` I've tried searching online but I feel like I haven't made much progress. How would I go about setting up a logger and telling it to write in my development log file?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I think you should use it like this in your method.  Checkout [section 2.3](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger) here

```
def your_method  
  logger.debug "This is from debug"
  logger.info "This is from info"
end
```

Answer (score 8):

rails has an easy logging mechanism

from inside controller/model

```
logger.info 'some info'
logger.error 'some error'
```

etc.

From Outside these Rails's sections, in Plain Old Ruby objects such as service objects, library objects, you can easily access the same default logger

for rails < 3

```
logger = RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER
logger.info 'some info'
logger.error 'some error'
```

for rails > 3

```
logger = Rails.logger
logger.info 'some info'
logger.error 'some error'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `Rails.logger` in a Plain Old Ruby Object or `ServiceObject`, then you will need to include it manually:

```
class MyService
  def initialize(foo)
    @logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
    @foo = foo
  end

  def call
    do_something
  end

  private

  def do_something
    @logger.debug { "do_something called! With #{@foo.class} class" }
  end
end
```

Result:

```
MyService.new(Bar.new).call
# [2018-01-27T00:17:22.167974 #57866] DEBUG -- : do_something called! With Bar class
```

Answer (score 0):

If no logger output appears in your log file, then check to what value log_level has been set in your environments file (config/environments/development.rb, ...)
It should either not bee there (default is :debug) or

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

should be set. Other values are:

```
:debug, :info, :warn, :error, :fatal, :unknown
```

More information here:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html
section 2.2 Log levels