# Rails.logger doesn't log the data into development.log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I simple question:

```
# development.rb
config.log_level = :debug


class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :my_log

  private

  def my_log 
    Rails.logger.debug <<-LOG
      [CUSTOM DEBUG] 
        some info 123
        #{request.method.inspect}
        ...

    LOG
  end
```

And still after that `development.log` is empty.

UPDATE:

It does log the requests, but to the terminal, not to development.log

Comment: Just to be sure: you're in the development environment, right?

Comment: And you know *for a fact* that the method is being called?

Comment: @Jon, I put a binding.pry in it.

Comment: What happens when you print out `Rails.logger` in the pry? (Add the output to your question)

Comment: @Jon, it shows the data. However, it actually logs (sometimes?) the data to the console, but not to a file. how come?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. But this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749804/using-logger-in-rails-4 Apparently, you should just use `logger.debug` without the `Rails.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make sure the user running the Rails server has write permissions to the log file?

I've seen this happen if the server is started as `root` the first time

```
sudo rails s
```

which created the development.log file owned by root.
Then if a non-privileged user starts the server

```
rails s
```

the log file cannot be written to because it's owned by root.