# logger in google-cloud-logging is not working for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-logging

I'm currently working on the GCP and deployed my rails app on the GCP instance.
I'm currently using https://github.com/brendeschuijmert/google-cloud-ruby/tree/master/google-cloud-logging for the compute engine.

When I use this on the rails application.

`Rails.logger.info "Hello World"` works well.

But `logger.warn "Hola Mundo"` is not working.

I want someone shade some light on this problem.

Thanks

Comment: You mean `Rails.logger.warn` isn't working? or you're trying to use the command with the `Rails` prefix?

Comment: Thank you @Vidur. `Rails.logger.warn` is also working well. But `logger.warn` is not working. I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: What is the error message that you get? and where are you trying to call the logger from - a controller/model?

Comment: I'm trying to use logger inside the `application_controller.rb`. And I can't get any error when I use `logger` instead of `Rails.logger`

Comment: Did you ever have the chance to check the Cloud Logging library [1] for Ruby provided by Google?

There are some Ruby samples for Stackdriver [2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/ruby

[2] https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ruby-docs-samples/blob/d89b8285ba5d939aefd5bae7070522ebcdfef3b8/stackdriver/Gemfile

Comment: Yes, it's still not working. This issue is related to https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/issues/7644

Comment: A comment on the GIT issue you found:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/issues/7644
To add to what user "mattes" commented there would be useful

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to call `logger` from outside of a controller/model or some other file that is a part of Rails' structure - you will have to explicitly create a logger for yourself with:

```
logger = Logger.new(STDOUT) # Or wherever you want to log to
```

However if `Rails.logger` is working, then you likely just need an alias like `logger = Rails.logger` to allow you to use `logger.warn` without the Rails namespace prefix. You're probably in a file that doesn't already have a helper that is aliasing that for you.

Some more digging in the API reveals that the `logger` stems from `ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber` - several classes like `ActionController` include child `LogSubscriber`s that inherit from that module and hence have the `logger` method available to them. You can manually alias it to `Rails.logger` to have it work for you wherever you are trying to invoke it.

Source: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/LogSubscriber.html#method-c-logger

Comment: Thank you Vidur!, please allow me to add something to this.

I think we can read more about this on:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749804/using-logger-in-rails-4

And sections 2.2 & 2.3 of this Ruby documentation:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels

Also a comment on the GIT issue they found:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/issues/7644
To add to what user "mattes" commented there would be good.